# ScrollView as a Custom Control

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am implementing an app where in every page I have got an horizontal menu as a scroll view, where the labels of some buttons can change in response of some actions pushed by the user. These labels must remain the same in every page.

Is it correct to use a custom control for the purpose of mantaining the labels, considering the template bound to a specific viewModel?

Morover, to achieve this result I put a custom control in the resource dictionary of App.xaml file, but I am unable to reference it  in the page where I want to use the template, because scroll view doesn't have ControlTemplate property.

Thank you in advance

**App.xaml**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
                <controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView BackgroundColor="#fcb1b1b1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="8, 24" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HeightRequest="100">
                <!-- template code here -->     
                </controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView>
```

**RootPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    x:Class="com.v2home.v2AppTool.Views.RootPage"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:com.v2home.v2AppTool.ViewModels"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:com.v2home.v2AppTool.Controls"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:com.v2home.v2AppTool.ViewModels" x:DataType="viewmodels:AutomationViewModel"
    x:Name="rootPage"
>
    <StackLayout>
        <controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
            
        </controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView>
        <ContentView>
            <Label Text="My text"></Label>
        </ContentView>
    </StackLayout>
```

## Update 1

That's my header template and TopButton is the button I want with the same label in every page. This button has bound to a converter that converts a bool to a string. What happen is that the bool variable, `IsConnected`,  passed to the converter is not the same and in every page the label is different. What I understand is that every instance of `HeaderTemplate` has its own instance of `MainViewModel`.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
                <controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView BackgroundColor="#fcb1b1b1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="8, 24" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HeightRequest="100">
                    <controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView.BindingContext>
                        <local:MainViewModel/>
                    </controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView.BindingContext>
                    <controls:TouchResponsiveScrollView.Content>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="18" MinimumHeightRequest="100">
                              <controls:TopButton ContentLayout="Top" Text="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource boolToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter='CommunicationLabel'}"
```

That's my MainViewModel. Also if I mark as static `_isConnected`, the label is not not the same in every page.

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel{

  private  bool _isConnected;
  public bool IsConnected
        {
            set
            {
                if (_isConnected != value)
                {
                    _isConnected = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
            get {
                    return _isConnected;}
        }         
}
```

Comment: Use a `ContentView`. That takes a `ControlTemplate`. (It wouldn't be correct to have `TouchResponsiveScrollView` both in the Page declaration AND in the Template declaration - you want a "generic" object like "ContentView", to assign the template to.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve , thank you very much. But is it possibile to build a scrollable view with a content view?

Comment: Ah, I was not clear. Make a ContentView, which has that ControlTemplate. `<StackLayout> <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"> </StackLayout>`. Don't put a ScrollView in RootPage.xaml; you get the ScrollView via the ControlTemplate.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, yes xaml must be the same in every page, placeholder `<!-- template code here -->` is only for shorting the code.

Comment: Could you please clarify your needs? Do you want to use the ScrollView as a ControlTemplate as a whole, or do you want to use a Button as a ControlTemplate. You can refer to this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#consume-a-controltemplate, directly use ContentView's ControlTemplate after creating ControlTemplate Attributes.

Comment: Good that's the easy case. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ContentView` accepts a control template, which can contain any view hierarchy. Your control template is fine. To have shared contents on every page, the BindingContext of the template should point to static data.

Put the properties that need to be "shared" between pages, into their own viewmodel. In that class, declare a static property to contain the single shared instance:

```
// in namespace YourNameSpace
public class CommonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged   // exact declaration depends on MVVM library used.
{
    // static Singleton.
    // "{ get; }": it is a Property.
    public static CommonViewModel It { get; } = new CommonViewModel();

    // --- declare the properties of CommonViewModel to share ---

    private MyType1 _myProperty1;
    public MyType1 MyProperty1 {
        get => _myProperty1;
        set {
            if (_myProperty1 != value) {
                _myProperty1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty1");   // Or see your MVVM library docs.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At top of XAML file containing ControlTemplate

```
<...
    xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
```

Have template bind to that static property:

```
< ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate" BindingContext="{x:Static mynamespace:CommonViewModel.It}">
```

Use template like this:

```
<ContentPage
    ...
>
    <StackLayout>
        ... other content on page ...
        <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" />
        ... other content on page ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: from a graphic point of view is ok, but I noticed that for every page I open the control template is instantiated; in this way the labels inside the buttons in the scroll view are different. The ideal situation is one instance of the control template referring the same view model. In this way I sholud have the same top menu in every page with the same label.

Comment: @zappasan - Show code for one of the buttons that should remain the same. To stay the same, the template needs to have a different BindingContext. By default it inherits BindingContext from Page.

Comment: Ops sorry I didn't see your updated answer...I try.

Comment: It works!!! Thank You  for tour time and patience @ToolmakerSteve